# Offline Map, using indexeddb and JSON files

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

i want to make an offline map, using topoJSON and openlayers to generate the map.

I put the JSON into a indexeddb as a blob and try to convert the blob back to an JSON. Everything works find till i want to convert the blob back. I get the error: [object%20Promise] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found),

(Dexie is just a indexeddb wrapper)

```js
    var db = new Dexie("json_db");
db.version(1).stores({
    jsons: '++id'
});

getBlobAndPutInDB("https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/topojson/world-110m.json");

function initMap() {

    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#319FD3',
            width: 1
        })
    });

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({

            url: blobToJSON(),
            format: new ol.format.TopoJSON({
                layers: ['countries']
            }),
            overlaps: false
        }),
        style: style
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 1
        })
    });

}

async function blobToJSON() {

    let blob = await db.jsons.get(2);
    var file = new File([blob], "map.json", { type: "application/json", lastModified: Date.now() });
    return file;
}

function getBlobAndPutInDB(url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var myBlob = this.response;
            db.jsons.put(myBlob);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@latest/dist/dexie.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="OfflineMap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>initMap();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe someone knows what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a promise to the url here: url: `blobToJSON()`. You need to resolve the promise before you can use the result.